# Matlab loop optimization - Logical Indexing

Tags: matlab, matrix, optimization, indexing

I've got a serious performance issue with the matlab code bellow. It runs but the loop takes a lot of time and i would like to optimize it. Can anyone help me rewrite this as logical indexing?

Many thanks!

```
j = 0

for i = 1:n
 if varA(i) < varB(i)
    varC(i) = varD(i);
 else
    varC(i) = varB(i);
    j = j + 1;
 end
end
```

Comment: Could you provide more information on how `varA`, `varB`, `varC` and `varD` look?

Comment: @Axel they are  double type matrix variables of rather large dimensions

Comment: I haven't had the chance yet. But I'll let you know as soon as I do @Axel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally your loop should be equal to the following snippet:

```
varC(varA < varB) = varD(varA < varB);
varC(varA >= varB) = varB(varA >= varB);
```

However I would need more information on how `varA`, `varB`, `varC` and `varD` look to verify that this solution works.

Comment: @Adriaan OP answered already that the input are double arrays of large dimension. I tested this answer against a variety of double arrays. Really don't understand your concerns. I just wrote I can't "verify" if it actually works in OPs case as I don't have the actual arrays. However there is no reason to assume it wouldn't work. I find it rather rude to label this as a guessing answer.

Comment: @Axel it works! Thank you for your help I really appreciate it